# Modal bottom sheet changes status bar color

Tags: android, android-statusbar

Standard BottomSheetDialogFragment changes my status bar color to this ugly greenish thing and I can't change it to any other color. Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700645/set-status-bar-color-from-dialogfragment) but it doesn't work.
Any thoughts?

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ukW7.png): [Status bar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ukW7.png)

This is my dialog class:

```
public class BottomSheetExample extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, container, false);
        // Code below only changes status bar color to black after bottom
        // sheet closes, not while it's open like it should
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack, null));
            }
            else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                }
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

and this is bottom_sheet layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bottom Sheet Example" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I call it from MainActivity like this:

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment dialogFragment = new BottomSheetExample();
dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by using:

```
dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

Comment: FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS is deprecated. It suggests to use window?.statusBarColor

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting `backgroundDimEnabled` in `Activity`’s theme, which dims the window behind the `Activity`, like when a `Dialog` is shown. Even though our `Activity` only peeks at the bottom, it still essentially occupies the whole screen. We wouldn’t want to leave the impression that users can interact with the Activity behind, so let’s dim it.

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Translucent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

**your XML file**

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/touch_outside"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior".../>
```

**MainActivity**

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setStatusBarDim(true);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    findViewById(R.id.touch_outside).setOnClickListener(v -> finish());
    BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet))
      .setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
          switch (newState) {
            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN:
              finish();
              break;
            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED:
              setStatusBarDim(false);
              break;
            default:
              setStatusBarDim(true);
              break;
          }
        }
        ...
    });
  }

  private void setStatusBarDim(boolean dim) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      getWindow().setStatusBarColor(dim ? Color.TRANSPARENT :
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, getThemedResId(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark)));
    }
  }

  private int getThemedResId(@AttrRes int attr) {
    TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{attr});
    int resId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
    a.recycle();
    return resId;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know, but that is not the problem here. Problem is that modal BottomSheetDialogFragment changes it when it's active. I need it to be in dark tint as the rest of the screen, not blue/green like in screenshot I posted.

Comment: Then? Could you please elaborate, I guess I have the fix for that too :)

Comment: I edited my previous comment with detailed explanation.

Comment: Bro, Can I have your code, please. This problem seems to be quite uncanny

Comment: Tried your edited answer but it doesn't work. I edited my question with relevant code listings.